# Regarding same header and footer across web pages in HTML

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am developing a website and i want to have same header and footer across all web pages. Request you to please suggest me how i can do that.

Regards

Comment: This question is very vague so I'm not going to leave an actual answer but if you want to serve HTML pages with Javascript then look into NodeJS and the Express framework. Sounds like you need to start with a server-side layout page and learn from there.

Comment: Make separate header file and put only content you want show in all pages for header and also make separate file for footer and put footer content and include both file in every page you want , simple as that.

Comment: Creating separate header and footer files and including in all other pages is OK.I am looking for some other way by which this can be achieved.

Comment: Your question is very broad. You should paste some code and where are you struggling. As others said, to seperate header and footer in different files is common. So why you are still looking for another way and trying to invent the wheel new?

Answer (score 1):

Since you use JSP, you can use template :

`<%@include file='header.jsp'%>`

and

`<%@include file='footer.jsp'%>`

in your jsp pages.

Comment: Also for footer `<%@include file='footer.jsp'%>`. JSP file should be better here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response and this is ok but is there no other way i can achieve this so that i don't have to include header and footer file everywhere.